# Can Hindus go to foreign countries?

Tags: caste-system, manu-smriti, india, mleccha

1. Is it true that Hindus who go to foreign countries lose their caste  ?
2. Is such restrictions only on crossing the sea ? Or Is it applicable for leaving Aryavrata in any possible way, even by road ?
3. What is the remedy for this , if someone has gone to foreign countries ? Is there any repentance for it ?

Comment: Related: [What do Scriptures say about doing Puja/Archanas in “Mleccha Deshas”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15539/what-do-scriptures-say-about-doing-puja-archanas-in-mleccha-deshas/15542#15542)

Comment: See: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34567/is-crossing-the-ocean-samudrollanghana-a-taboo-in-hinduism

Comment: And this one: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/how-to-recover-from-lost-caste-status-after-crossing-an-ocean?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: And if Hindus cannot go to foreign countries, why are there brahmin priests in temples in foreign countries? How did Southeast Asia, Sri Lanka, Bali Indonesia all become Hindu before turning to Buddhism?

Comment: Similar - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23954/clarification-on-loosing-caste-due-to-samudrolanghana-sea-voyage